# How to loop through an object inside an array in Vuejs template?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2

I have an object inside an array. I'm having a challenge on how to loop through it.

My data looks like this:

[image: the data]

This is the snippet. I'm sure I am doing it in a wrong way.

```
<div v-for="(mes, i) in message" :key="mes.id">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <textarea name="text" id="input-message" v-model="mes[i].text" class="materialize-textarea"  data-length="200"></textarea>
                        <label for="input-message">Message</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Please I want to know the workaround it. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please explain more specifically what you are trying to achieve. You want to loop through the object that is inside an array? Why do you want to loop over the object instead of just accessing its attributes? Could you show what you have tried?

Comment: I have attached the image of what I did @rob

Comment: I want to loop through it because I have more than one of the objects inside the `message` array

Comment: Why exactly are you using textarea to display? Textarea is used to input longer texts. use div or p to display..

Comment: @DanteTheSmith that is not the issue. The result is for the textarea, I used it on purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Generic way would be, assuming you got message available,

```
<ul id="v-for-object" class="demo">
  <li v-for="value in message">
    {{ value.campaign_id }} ... {{ value.created_at }} ... your other properties listed in brackets
  </li>
</ul>
```

For more details you have to expose me more of your code.